# Deleting folders present on remote machine using batch file

Tags: batch-file, directory

I want to delete couple of folders using batch file.
But problem is that **these folders are present on some other machine**.
But I **can take the remote access to this machine** on my machine.

Please help me with this issue. I don't have any idea about this.

Comment: a simple batch file which will run by double clicking it...

Comment: do you have access to run batch file on that remote machine?

Answer (score 3):

A less comprehensive, but more simple answer...

```
del /F \\myserver\w_root$\users\selah\selah.txt
del /F \\myserver\w_root$\users\selah\status.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as you can mount the remote folder with a user who has delete authority, you can simply do something like this:

```
rem Set up the remote path - assuming it is sharable
set MY_DIR=\\10.1.1.1\some\path

rem Mount the remote path
net use %MY_DIR% %MY_PASSWORD% /USER:%MY_USER%

rem Delete a file
if exist "%MY_DIR%\MyFile" del /F "%MY_DIR%\MyFile" >nul

rem Unmount the remote path
net use %MY_DIR% /delete >nul
```

If you want to remove folders, you'll just need to make sure the mount point is at least one level above where you'll be deleting.